# SSRS Report Footer

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008-r2

I know about Page Footer, and I know I can make it look like Report Footer by controlling the visibility of Page Footer.

I want Report Footer it only shows in the very last page of the report.

The problem with the work around above is that it will reserve the space for the page footer and because what I want to be in report footer is quiet large in size (almost one third of the page) the Page footer work around is not a good solution.

Anyone has any other idea how to fix that?

I am using SSRS 2008 R2

Comment: One alternative maybe could be adding the footer data at the end of your report body instead of the footer

Comment: this will not make the footer data at the end of the last page.. it will be just after the report body.

Comment: I have tested it and it works. You have to size your report height to match your print page size, and move the "footer" fields at the report bottom. The only disadvantage I can think is the tablix last page size makes the "footer" print in a page it self

Comment: thats one thing, the other it is not aligned to the bottom of the page

Comment: Since footer can not be hidden or resized with custom expressions, I cannot think somethink better than what I have already suggested. I hope someone else has a better idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this and it works.

Right click the textbox or item you want to hide in your footer and go to properties. Click the visibility tab in the properties pane. Check show or hide based on expression and enter this code in the expression:

> =IIF(Globals!PageNumber = Globals!TotalPages, False, True)

This will hide your footer for all pages except the last.

Comment: but it will reserve its space